# CSS select parent element

Tags: css, css-selectors

Supposing I have a HTML like this

```
<label><input type="radio" checked></label>
<label><input type="radio"></label>
```

Question: how can I select the label of a checked radio in this case?

Comment: A bit of [research](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to achieve is not possible in CSS3.. if you want, you can wrap the elements inside a container, and position them either by floating, or by using `position: absolute;`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xQs37/) (Not relevant as you've not provided any specific code, but I've shared a general example here)

```
div.wrap label {
    float: left;
}

.wrap input[type=radio]:checked + label {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In CSS3, there's currently no way to do that.

What you should do is add a class to your `label`s, then target that class.

For reference, they're looking to include this in the [CSS 4 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#subject) which would use the notation:

```
!label > input[type="radio"]:only-child
```

But that's not supported by any browsers yet (as it isn't even finalised).